# Angularjs how can I reload the content

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I have this code that loads the content when the page load,
Now I want to know how to reload the content by clicking the button.
Can you show me how to do it with example please?

Javascript code:

```js
.controller('InterNewsCtrl', function($scope, NewsService) {

$scope.events = [];
 
  $scope.getData = function() {
    NewsService.getAll().then(function (response) {
    $scope.events = response;
          
      
    }), function (error) {
        
       
    } 
  
  };
    
 
$scope.getData(); // load initial content.

})
```

```html
Html code:

<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button>Voltar</ons-back-button>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
      <ons-toolbar-button><ons-icon icon="ion-android-refresh"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>

      <div class="center">Internacional</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
```

Comment: reload entire page? `location.reload()`

Comment: if you want to reload route then should use `$route.reload()`

Comment: I meant reload the content

Comment: you should use $scope.$digest() to refresh the values.

Comment: Can you show me a working example?

Comment: Angular has a two way data binding and if you change your `$scope` your view will change accordingly. So if your service does not cache the result it should work like your code suggests.

Comment: Add `ng-click="getData()"` to your refresh button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking how to just retrieve new events from the backend.  If that's correct, you don't need to reload the entire page.

You already have a function called getData which goes and retrieves you data via your service.  Assuming your service doesn't cache the data, just call getData from your button:

```
<ons-toolbar-button ng-click="getData()"><ons-icon icon="ion-android-refresh"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
```

P.S. if you do explicitly have the cache set to true in your service, you can remove the cached data with `$cacheFactory.get('$http').removeAll();`.

Answer (score 0):

For reloading same page in angular Js without post back

first remove that url from **template cache** if you call `$route.reload()` without removing it from `$templateCache`  it will get it from cache and it will not get latest content

Try following code

```
$scope.getdata=function()
{
    var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
    $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
    $route.reload();
}
```

and Call it as following

```
<input type="button" ng-click="getdata();" value ="refresh"/>
```

Hope this will help

Please reffer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816722/angular-reload-current-route-and-reload-the-current-template)

Comment: Seems it works check [this](http://kcdipesh.com.np/improve-your-ionicframework-performance-with-template-caching/)   `ionic (0.9.26)`  supports templatecache

Comment: I realized OP is using onsen not ionic anyway.  Still, I don't understand your recommendation.  There's already a $scope.getData function defined by the OP -- seems confusing to also have $scope.getdata as well.

Comment: I just changed it for example that how you will reload page

Comment: I'm not using ngRoute, because using  a onsen ui framework and it uses another way to navigate. All I need is a working example from my code because I'm learning javascript.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the implementation, but I'm just suggesting that you call it refreshPage or something.