# Reload A Partial Template with AJAX After $http Post Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm still relatively new to AngularJS so bear with me on this one. I'm trying to create a photo-liking system and when the user clicks the like button, it increases the number of likes. I have this functionality down, but the only thing is that I have to reload the page in order for the "like" to show. This means that everything on the backend is in order. However, I would like to prevent having to do reload the page.

One thing to note is that I have a partial template, and a HTTP post request occurs once the button is clicked with an `ng-click` directive.

**HTML SNIPPET FROM PARTIAL TEMPLATE**

```
<a class="like" ng-click="likeIt(//PHPCODEGOESHERE//)">Like</a>
```

**AngularJS**

```
userApp.controller('photoController',['$scope','$location','$window','$log','$route','$routeParams','$location','$http', function($scope,$location,$window,$log,$route,$routeParams,$location,$http){
    $scope.name = 'Photos';
    $scope.likeIt = function(parameters){
        $http.post('centralcommand.php', {id: parameters}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            window.location.reload(); // Causes page to reload
               }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            alert('failure');
        });
    };

}]);
```

Please also note that I have tried to change the `innerHTML` in the success callback. This doesn't work because I already am mixing PHP with HTML and I have to use both `'` and `"` in the HTML code so when I get the HTML text and replace it using `innerHTML` it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer after perusing a different method and it comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816722/angular-reload-current-route-and-reload-the-current-template) answer provided in a separate StackOverflow post. It has to do with reloading the template cache using the `$templateCache` service:

```
userApp.controller('photoController',['$scope','$location','$window','$log','$route','$routeParams','$location','$http','$templateCache', function($scope,$location,$window,$log,$route,$routeParams,$location,$http,$templateCache){
    $scope.name = 'Photos';
    var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl; // ADDITION # 1
    $scope.routeReloader = function(parameters){
        $http.post('centralcommand.php', {id: parameters}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);   // ADDITION # 2
            $route.reload();                              // ADDITION # 3
               }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            alert('failure');
        });
    };

}]);
```