# Meteorjs + Angular2 click link does not re-render page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, web-component

Using **MeteorJS** and **Angular 2.0**

On home page that has a link called **Login**.

When clicked, user is routed to login page, and associated Angular2 Components are rendered correctly.

Now on login page, which has a link to return to home page.

Click on link and navigate to home page, then re-click login page.

User is routed correctly, but Angular2 Components do not re-render.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "Angular2 Components do not re-render"? Does the page not show any content at all? Does it render with the wrong or outdated content? A look at the components might be helpful.

Comment: The angular2 components has an associated template. The template renders on page load, but not when redirecting from a previous page.

Comment: @SoEzPz You need to provide far more context, like your actual code and preferably an example in a plunkr, codepen, etc... showing the issue.

Comment: This is not a code issue, its a framework issue with cacheing, like turbo-links in RAILS; the same issue occurs. It should be common enough with those of us experimenting with these newer technologies that perhaps someone knows the fix.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking for known issues on templates and reloading pages. One issue is about templates being mixed in cache, which is fixed with clearing the cache as follows:

```
var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
$route.reload();
```

**Source:**

[Angular reload current route and reload the current template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816722/angular-reload-current-route-and-reload-the-current-template)

Comment: I'm not using the Angular router. Perhaps this is why? I'm using Iron Router  - part of Meteorjs.