# Angular/Angular2, Refresh Component From routerLink (NavBar) , If already in existing route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

If i am on same route , and i click again from nav bar. It doesn't do anything .

How can I refresh my component from navbar itself. Is there any method in routerLink.

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/campaigns']">Creative</a></li>
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/market-survey']">Survey</a></li>
```

click again means, suppose you click on creative (in my example) corresponding route will activate and component is loaded . Then I again click on creative . I want that component should refresh

Comment: Is this what you are seeking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816722/angular-reload-current-route-and-reload-the-current-template

Comment: No I am asking for Angular 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983055/how-to-reload-the-current-route-with-the-angular-2-router

Comment: No @KishanMundha, I want reload from HTML

Comment: In HTML we are using `[routerLink]` directive, which internally using `navigate()` function and when we are already on same route, it ignore next process. If you want to refresh whole page, you can try `location.reload()`. but this will reload full page.

Comment: please avoid silly answers @KishanMundha

Comment: what do you mean clicking again? do you mean clicking the same route and refresh the data in your other component? Also, it woud be helpful if you include your component.ts

Comment: @brijmcq click again means, suppose you click on creative (in my example) corresponding route will activate and component is loaded . Then I again click on creative . I want that component should refresh

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed this by creating another component

> refresh.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-refresh',
     template: `
       <p>
         refresh Works!
       </p>
     `,
     styles: []
   })
   export class RefreshComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private route:Router) { }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.activatedRoute
           .queryParams
           .subscribe(params => {                
             if(params.url){
               this.route.navigate([params.url]);
             }
           });
     }

   }
```

app.routing

{path: 'refresh',component:RefreshComponent},

and my new naviation li is

```
   <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/refresh']" [queryParams]="{url:'campaigns'}" skipLocationChange="true">My AMP Creative</a></li>
```